# item not shown on action bar

Tags: android, menu

i have an action bar, i don't understand why with this code the menu items inside action bar are not shown.

main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.foo.activity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:icon="@drawable/button1"
        android:onClick="clickEvent"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/button1">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/log_out"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/log_out"/>
    </item>

</menu>
```

and

```
// create action bar menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

it alwasy show this:

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: why put item inside another item??? change android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" to android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: @MHP with your's suggestion i got `inflateException` on `onCreateOptionMenu`

Comment: answer below is true,you got error because you forgot to put /> at end of item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the items, because an `item` is not allowed within another `item`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.foo.activity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:icon="@drawable/button1"
        android:onClick="clickEvent"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/button1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/log_out"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/log_out"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but inside the xml i' m not allowed to do that,because it says to me `Error in an XML file: aborting build.` I' ve to insert `</item>` at the end of the file.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku if the item element has no children (which it can't have) using `/>` is the same as `</item>`. Make sure you entered it right, as in my example.

Comment: well i forgot, `/` at the firt item, distraction error, thanks a lot anyway.